# Output of Sybase stored procedure call issue

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sybase

I have a Sybase stored procedure signature like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGui_AddENtity (@entity varchar(10), @category varchar(100),
                                              @debug smallint = 0,
                                              @retval smallint output, @errmsg varchar(255) output)
```

I am trying to execute it in C# but it is complaining about missing the retval param. Would you know why? I can't figure it out, I've tried many things already...

```
        // Adding also extra output params and debug one
        AseParameter extraParam = command.CreateParameter();
        extraParam.ParameterName = "@retval";
        extraParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
        extraParam.AseDbType = AseDbType.SmallInt;
        extraParam.Value = 0;
        command.Parameters.Add(extraParam);

        extraParam.ParameterName = "@errmsg";
        extraParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
        extraParam.AseDbType = AseDbType.NChar;
        extraParam.Value = "null";
        command.Parameters.Add(extraParam);

        // Finally executing the query`
        try
        {
            var retval = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The logs:

> 2013-09-19T16:51:31.293297 [INFO ] {Thread: UI} Param - Name: @retval,
>   Value: 0, DbType: Int16, AseDbType: SmallInt, Direction: InputOutput
>   2013-09-19T16:51:31.293297 [INFO ] {Thread: UI} Param - Name: @errmsg,
>   Value: null, DbType: AnsiStringFixedLength, AseDbType: NChar,
>   Direction: InputOutput 2013-09-19T16:51:31.324555 [ERROR] {Thread: UI}
>   Procedure spGui_AddNewRegularName expects parameter @retvals, which
>   was not supplied.
>      at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.CheckResult(Int32 res)    at
>   Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.Execute()    at
>   Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a C# issue for dummies... had to create parameter each time instead of using the previous one, i.e. put at the begining of each block:

```
AseParameter extraParam = command.CreateParameter();
```

Also, another issue was that I needed to set the direction to:

```
extraParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```